# Variable location for intial value in ParametericNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to figure out if *Mathematica* allows a variable location for a known initial value for `ParametricNDSolve`.  I haven't been able to find an example where this is done.

In the following I set `w[5.7] == 0` as an initial condition, but I would rather set `w[p] == 0`, or in some other way find the largest `p` for which the solution of interest exists.  The solution of interest requires `w[y] >= 0` in the range `{ y, 1, p}`, so I plot `Sqrt[w]` there.  Sorry about all the initial variables etc. The adjustable parameter `c` is to be anything in the range `{ 0, 1}` but here `0.2` is used.

```
{la, ra, ta, sa} = {0.06, 0.00002, 298., 5.6705*10^-8}; 
{roa, rex} = {5.6*10^(-8), 1.209} ; ro[y_] = roa*y^rex; 
{ka, kc, kex} = {179., 0.9624, -0.2792}; k[y_] = ka*kc*y^kex;
{ga, g0, g1, g2, g3, g4} = {   0.0237,    1.09104, -0.751912, 
                             0.792915, -0.0862438,  0.0029868};

g[y_] = ga*(g0 + g1*y + g2*y^2 + g3*y^3 + g4*y^4);
{fa, f1, f2} = {1.001, -0.001076, -0.0000635}; 
f[y_] = fa + f1*y + f2*y^2;
r[y_] = ra/f[y];
a[y_] = kex/y - 2.*(f1 + 2.*f2*y)/f[y];
b[y_, c_] = ((c^2)*ro[y]/Pi^2/r[y]^3 - 2.*sa*(ta^4)*g[y]*(y^4 - 1.))* la^2/ta/r[y]/k[y];

wsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ w'[y] + 2*a[y]*w[y]^2 + 2*b[y, c] == 0,
                                w[5.7] == 0}, w, {y, 1, 12}, {c}];
Plot[ Sqrt[wsol[0.2][y]], {y, 1, 12}, PlotRange -> {{1, 12}, {-1, 10}},
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True]
```

I get a nice graph with a $2$-branch solution, and it varies with parameter `c`, but I'd like to include the parameter `p` to be used in the initial condition `w[p] == 0`. At the largest `p = pmax`, the solution approaches a double root, somewhere between $5$ and $6$ in this example.  That number is needed for further work - basically, what is `pmax[c]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always introduce a new independent variable $\psi$, so when $y$ runs from $1$ to $p$, $\psi$ runs from $0$ to $1$:

```
ψ == Rescale[y, {1, p}, {0, 1}]
```

> $\psi =\frac{y-1}{p-1}$

Thus the ODE becomes

```
eqs2 = {2 b[1 - ψ + p ψ, c] + 2 a[1 - ψ + p ψ] ω[ψ]^2 + Derivative[1][ω][ψ]/(-1 + p) == 0,
        ω[1] == 0};
```

Which can be solved by `ParametricNDSolveValue`:

```
ωsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqs2, ω, {ψ, 0, 1}, {c, p}]
```

Plotting out the solution is straightforward:

```
With[{c = .2},
    Table[
            Plot[
                Sqrt[ωsol[c, p][-(1/(-1 + p)) + y/(-1 + p)]],
                {y, 1, p},
                PlotRange -> {All, {-1, All}},
                PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[p, {1, 6}]],
                Frame -> True],
            {p, 5.9, 1.1, -.5}] // Show
    ]
```

[image: solution vs c]

Or even combine the variation against `c` and `p` together:

```
Module[{cmin = .2, cmax = 2, logcStep = .3, pmin = 1.1, pmax = 5.9, 
        pStep = .3},
    Table[
                With[{c = cv},
                    Plot[
                        Sqrt[ωsol[c, p][-(1/(-1 + p)) + y/(-1 + p)]],
                        {y, 1, p},
                        PlotRange -> {All, {-1, All}},
                        PlotStyle -> Lighter[
                                ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[p, {pmin, pmax}]],
                                Rescale[c, {cmin, cmax}, {0, .9}]]
                        ]
                    ],
                {cv, Reverse@
                        Exp[Join[Range[Log[cmin], Log[cmax], logcStep], {Log[cmax]}]]},
                {p, pmax, pmin, -pStep}
                ] // Flatten // Show[#, Frame -> True] &
    ]
```

[image: solution vs c and p]

Comment: Rescale is helpful - I am still seeking how to locate the extreme value pmax[c] but rainbow plot also is helpful for that - shows color reversal in neghborhood of the extremum.

Comment: @DeanLangley Hi Dean, I'm not sure what you mean by *At the largest `p = pmax`, the solution approaches a double root* in your OP.

Comment: I mean w[p1]==0 gives a solution w that crosses 0 at p1, but it usually crosses at another p2 also.  I want p1<p2, never p2<p1 (because then there are negative values between 1 and p1), and I think there is some p1=p2=pmax for which the solution w touches 0 without crossing.  I have been able to investigate this using your Rescale method and now have a better idea how to limit the range of useful p values. Thanks

Comment: @DeanLangley Glad I can help :)